# CURL request clarification

Tags: php, curl

I am calling below file in below 2 ways:-

```
1. CURL request
2. Ajax request in web site
```

http://test.com/test.php

In that scenarios , How to find out the file request comes from **CURL / Ajax request** without argument segregation.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the request IP address. The Ajax call request IP address will be the client's IP address, while on the CURL case it will be the server(or where the library is located) IP address.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the user-agent header. If starts with **curl**, indicates that the request was from a curl client.

Use the code `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];` to get the user agent.

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] return as empty while calling file thru CURL.

Comment: Weird, I tested it and worked... Does it return anything if u call by Ajax?

Comment: @karthik did you check it?